# sort some IDs strings with some numbers PHP

Tags: php

I have this for a `var_dump($productId)`:

```
string(1) "9"

string(2) "11"

string(2) "12"

string(2) "17"

string(2) "18"
```

Now, i want for example the function_x to not execute for id 18 and 17, so i want to make something like this:

```
$test=array('18','17');
if(!in_array($test,array($productId))){}
```

but seems not to be working, the idea is if i want to make for just 18 then:

```
$test=18;
if($test != $productId){}
```

and this is working, but how to do it for more than one number/ID ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From your var_dump($productId) it doesnt seem to be an array. Anyway . If it was than Antony's answer would do .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the other answers are assuming your `$productId` is an array. I'm guessing you are running var_dump() inside a foreach or something.

```
if(17 != $productId && 18 != $productId)
{
    // If $productId is not 17 and is not 18.
}

// Alternatively, if you want to add more IDs to ignore, you could use in_array.
$ignore = array(17,18,19,20);

if(false == in_array($productId,$ignore))
{
    // If $productId is not in the ignore array.
}
```

Comment: yes, the var_dump is in another stupid magento foreach, it seems correct how your code is but my problem is that i have a lot numbers not just two, and i need a solution for a lots of numbers

Comment: sorry didn't see the alternativ, i will give it a try :)

Comment: No worries. Note that the correct solution is to stop the product IDs coming through in the first place (ie, by updating the database query that pulls them out) - if you can that is. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

If you get `$productId` as a string one at a time:

```
if(!in_array($productId,$test)) {
    // execute function
}
```

If `$productId` is an array:

```
$test=array('18','17');
foreach ($productId as $id) {
    if(!in_array($id,$test)) {
        // execute function
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jimmy see updated answer. I thought `$productId` was an array.